# mootools | overwrite propery of a tween without create new tween everytime

Tags: mootools, javascript, tween

Is there a way to overwrite the property of a tween?
If I write

```
el.set('tween', {duration: ‘long’, onComplete: callback});
```

and then

```
el.set('tween', {duration: 200, onComplete: secondcallback });
```

I can’t replace the old property (callback is triggered again)

Is possible to solve this problem without the creation of a new Fx.Tween everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you set `onComplete` on the same instance, callbacks are pushed and associated with the same 'complete' event and each callback will be called after the event is fired.

To 'replace' the `onComplete` callback, you could use `removeEvent`, i.e.

```
el.set('tween', {duration: ‘long’, onComplete: callback});

//and then...

el.get('tween')
    .removeEvent('complete', callback)
    .addEvent('complete', secondcallback);
```

demo => http://jsfiddle.net/NNzQ7/

Comment: perfect, and if i want to overwrite the duration or the property attributes?

Comment: Properties like duration will be overwritten each time u set it, so u just need to do el.set('tween', {duration : newDuration});

Answer (score 0):

I would create two independent tweens and keep them around:

```
var fx1 = new Fx.Tween(element, {onComplete: callback});
var fx2 = new Fx.Tween(element, {onComplete: anothercallback});
```

And then you can use them individually:

```
fx1.start('background-color', 'cyan', 'red');
fx2.start('background-color', 'red', 'cyan');
```

Comment: it's not a good practice since mootools offers a tween instance directly 'inside' the element, so in the case reported by the OP it would be better to overwrite that tween instance's 'complete' event by removeEvent.